# Do you have to declare methods as synchronized in a ContentProvider to use SyncAdapter?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I am altering my application to start using `SyncAdapter` to sync with a server instead of my current implementation.

I created a `ContentProvider` class (MyDB) which uses an `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create an `SQLiteDatabase` and handle basic crud operations in the database

ContentProvider's impementation uses my class' methods in order to perform the crud operations needed by the SyncAdapter

So for example

```
Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
```

uses my class's

```
int do_insert(string table, string[] columns, string[] values)
```

and

```
 Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
```

uses my class's

```
Cursor do_query(string table, string[] columns, string query, string order)
```

do I have to declare my base methods (`do_insert`, `do_query`) as synchronized? does the `SyncAdapter` using the `ContentProvider` have ways to make sure that there are no problems? do I have to do something else to make sure no conflicts arise?

thanks in advance for any help you can provide